# Avoid classes to be registered in a COM+ Serviced Component

Tags: c#, registry, com+

I have a `COM+ DLL` that contains some classes that are primary and other auxiliary classes not used by the public methods. When registering the DLL using `regsvcs` command all the classes are added to registry and to TLB file.

There is any attribute or other solution to avoid adding the auxiliary classes to registry?

I have found `ComVisibleAttribute` attribute but it seems to be related only to inheritance.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you ticked the "Make assembly COM-visible" option.   Project + Properties, Application tab, Assembly Information button.  That causes *all* public classes in your project to be registered.  Turn it off, apply [ComVisible(true)] explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ComVisibleAttribute is the correct attribute to use. In AssemblyInfo.cs you can use

```
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
```

so that everything is *not* COM visible by default, and then for classes which you do want to be visible, precede them with

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyClass
```

Or flip it the other way round, if you want most types to be COM visible, and only a few to be invisible. I prefer everything invisible by default, as it gives me more control over exactly what is exposed to COM.